# Office 2007 constantly crashes, logged as Event ID 1000

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office

I have a user, who despite my best efforts, is having constant Office 2007 crashes.

I've tried deleting their profile and setting it up again, repairing office, uninstalling completely and then reinstalling, and swapping out memory sticks.

One event log error I keep getting is the following: (note all the Office errors are `event id 1000`)

```
Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 12.0.6539.5000, 
                                                      time stamp: 0x4c12486d
Faulting module name: EMSMDB32.DLL, version: 12.0.6539.5000, 
                                                      time stamp: 0x4c1246f8
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0005d8e2
Faulting process id: 0xf6c
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb6633f33384f3
Faulting application path: 
                C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE
Faulting module path: c:\progra~2\micros~1\office12\EMSMDB32.DLL
Report Id: 0d4a2eab-d231-11df-80a0-4061868f5d10
```

I also get this:

```
Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 12.0.6539.5000, 
                                                      time stamp: 0x4c12486d
Faulting module name: olmapi32.dll, version: 12.0.6538.5000, 
                                                      time stamp: 0x4bfc6ad9
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x002357a9
Faulting process id: 0x5e4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb661f4546aa77
Faulting application path: 
                C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE
Faulting module path: c:\progra~2\micros~1\office12\olmapi32.dll
Report Id: a4a90658-d224-11df-80a0-4061868f5d10
```

The Excel error is this:

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 12.0.6535.5002, 
                                                      time stamp: 0x4bd2a7f1
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, 
                                                      time stamp: 0x4a5bdbdf
Exception code: 0xe06d7363
Fault offset: 0x0000b727
Faulting process id: 0x14a8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb61ab7bc0abab
Faulting application path: 
                  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: ba0c454b-cd9e-11df-80a0-4061868f5d10
```

Also have gotten this for PowerPoint:

```
Faulting application name: POWERPNT.EXE, version: 12.0.6500.5000, 
                                                      time stamp: 0x49a68f9d
Faulting module name: COMShim.dll, version: 2010.3.325.110, 
                                                      time stamp: 0x4c51e0b1
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x0001e388
Faulting process id: 0x1480
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb5fe9a0660e81
Faulting application path: 
               C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\POWERPNT.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\FactSet\COMShim.dll
Report Id: e03d2a21-cbdc-11df-9bc8-4061868f5d10
```

(Some of the above lines edited to keep you from scroll horizontally.)

Lastly, I get this error several times a day, I don't think it is related but maybe it is:

> Failed extract of third-party root list from auto update cab at: http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab with error: A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.

Any ideas? This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Still having this issue. Working with M$ to try and resolve it.

Comment: When you uninstalled it did you remove all old office directories before reinstalling? If there are non-office .dll files causing problems they wouldn't be removed and if they are problematic enough to not let the uninstaller touch them, they would just cause problems on the next install.

Answer (score 1):

In your event log,  your faulting **KERNELBASE.dll** is interesting. A corrupt KERNELBASE.DLL is known for a lot of [applications crashing](https://www.google.com/search?q=KERNELBASE.dll) ..

try doing a `sfc /scannow` for integrity violations...

Answer (score 0):

I feel below files are non office files (I mean these files are not generated by office):-

```
EMSMDB32.DLL
olmapi32.dll
KERNELBASE.dll
COMShim.dll
```

These files you may have to delete manually.